# Как реализовать IPC в python 3.6 на основе базы данных?

Tags: python, ipc

**Как можно сделать общение между процессами, желательно на базе данных?**
В моем коде нету возможности оперативно обрабатывать получаемые данные из другого процесса, по этому я бы хотел наладить базу данных, что бы процессы могли записывать в нее данные, которые будет читать процесс обработки.

Comment: я думаю стоит использовать очереди. Например rabbitmq

Comment: вам вероятно не общий IPC нужно, а очередь задач типа [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)